# import ARCSI as module in python

Tags: gdal, remote-sensing, jupyter-notebook, conda

Any way to work with ARCSI (Atmospheric and Radiometric Correction of Satellite Imagery) like any other python package?

Can it be imported in a jupyter notebook?

```
>>>import arcsi
```

or is this only available through conda console?

Comment: Hi i have the same doubt about if there is the possibility to perform the TOA atmospheric correction from a python package since otherwise you have to create a specific environment and work from the command line. the answer listed here is not current, i don't know if it existed and no longer the package or it is not yet available. someone who has made progress on this? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.arcsi.remotesensing.info):

```
import arcsilib
arcsilib.arcsirun.SomeArcsiTool(AnARCSIParamsObj)
```